# Cordova - Play MKV file on windows (add codec to browser)

Tags: cordova, vlc, mkv

I have an MKV file with ac3 codec, that the browser can not play, because it lacks the ac3 codec, and there is no sound.

Is there a way using cordova to either use the computer's VLC or inject the needed codec to the browser it creates?

At first I was looking for a web solution, but because ac3 needs a license, I didn't find one. Then tried to find a cordova plugin that plays MKV perhaps, and couldn't find as well, so the final option I can think of is get a license and inject the codec somehow, or open it in VLC